# vim select word under cursor correctly

Tags: vim, exuberant-ctags

I ran ctags `ctags -R --extra=+f` from parent directory of my `C++` project
and when I go to vim I cannot jump to a header file because vim selects its name without an extension. However, when I say `:tag header.h` it works.
So there are two solutions:

1. somehow tell ctags not to include file extension in tags output
2. don't know if it's possible, but change vim's word selection algorithm

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `gf` instead.

Comment: @romainl what if I have `#include <internal/cache.h>`?

Comment: Well, you press `gf` on the filename.

Comment: @romainl what do you mean "on the filename", when i press `gf` whole string between angle brackets is selected, there's another option ctrl-] but in this case `cache` is selected and what I need is `cache.h`

Comment: `gf` doesn't select anything. `:help gf`.